# How do I cause "dnx ef dbcontext scaffold" not to emit an OnConfiguring() method?

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-database-first

I am doing database-first development in Entity Framework 7. When I generate my DbContext from the command line using

```
dnx ef dbcontext scaffold [connection string] EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer -o Models -c SomeContext
```

it is created with an `OnConfiguring(options)` method that hard-codes the connection string I used to create the model into the context.  I don't want this, because I want to use this code in multiple environments with different connection strings and, according to the documentation, [`OnConfiguring` has the highest precedence of all the ways of specifying configuration for a context](http://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext.html#combinations).

Can I cause `dbcontext scaffold` not to output the `OnConfiguring` method?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot currently customize the code scaffolded by EF Core. There is a workitem on EF to track this enhancement, which is currently in the backlog. See [Issue #4038](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4038) on GitHub.

Unfortunately this means you need to manually edit the code EF generates.